# Can C# allow to override the this keyword like in Javascript to make Jquery-like library possible?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, keyword

From
http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx

> When defining event handlers in
>   jQuery, the library will take care of
>   overriding the value of this and make
>   sure it contains a reference to the
>   element that was the source of the
>   event.
>
> How does jQuery override the value of
>   this? Keep reading.
>
> apply() and call()

Can C#/.NET give that same power ? If not how can one build a jquery-like library for C# not for javascript only ?

Comment: C#/.NET can't but node.js can.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to change `this` in C# but that is not required for building [fluent interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) with concepts like [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) (see the method chaining wiki page for an example in C#).

Comment: jquery is not reduced to fluent interfaces.

Comment: Of course not but I was assuming that is what you were referring to when you said 'jquery-like'.

Answer (score 0):

No, C# does not allow you to redefine language elements.

C# is a statically typed language whereas javascript is a dynamic language - just one difference that means you can't override language elements in C# but can in javascript.

Regardless, I don't quite see how you would write one library that would work for both javascript and C#.

Comment: I didn't say a single library, I say a jquery-like which would apply the same concepts of jquery to c# objects.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. `this` is a reserved keyword that is set automatically, and you **really** want it to point to the right place, ie, the current instance of the class.

Besides, what would exactly a 'jquery-like library for C#' be like? I don't think the concept makes much sense.

Comment: Why wouldn't make it sense ? Jquery is nothing specific to js or html in concepts ?

Comment: @user310291 then we must be talking about a different jquery, because  last i heard jquery IS a javascript library, featuring very convenient shorthands and cross-browser compatible implementations of javascript stuff that is clunky and error-prone to write. So I'd say it is *completely* specific to js. If the 'concepts' you mean are closures, or callbacks, or selectors, well, they aren't jquery-specific either, so *shrug*